# Configuration operations disappeared after putting a Javascript in the description part

Tags: jira

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e,context) {              
showHideFieldFunction();          
});           
showHideFieldFunction(); 
function showHideFieldFunction(){           
showHideField();           
$('#priority').change(function() {               
showHideField();           
});} 
function showHideField(){   
var selectedPriority=$("#priority").val(); 
//priority is HIGH show else hide
if(selectedPriority == '2'){ 
AJS.$('#customfield_11412').parent().show();
//AJS.$('#customfield_11412').closest('fieldset.group').show();
//$('#customfield_11412').closest('div.field-group').show();   
}
else{
AJS.$('#customfield_11412').parent().hide();
//AJS.$('#customfield_11412').closest('fieldset.group').hide();
//$('#customfield_11412').closest('div.field-group').hide();   
} 
}});
```

I put the above JavaScript the description part of the field configuration, but the fields below this field has been disappeared.
There was another script in another filed. Is it possible that the two scripts conflicted each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `</script>` tag at the end of your JavaScript.

Comment: You are right, but I cannot change the field description, because it is disappeared.

Comment: @Kalman You can try going to the URL `http://YOURJIRA/secure/admin/ConfigureCustomField!default.jspa?customFieldId=xxxxx` where xxxxx is the ID of the custom field you want to edit, and then click the "Edit Configuration" link to edit the description. If you don't know the custom field ID, you can extract it from the dB with `select id,cfname from customfield order by cfname`.